# How can I get the shape of an ee.Image?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I want to know the shape, that is the height and width of an ee.Image, how can i get that?

I have been looking through the documentation to see if there is a function for that, but I could not find, I have tried to get the value of the edges of my  geometry, which is a rectangle, and then calculate it's amplitude in x and y, but I get a very small result, which does not make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An ee.Image does not necessarily have a height or width if it has been  computed from multiple sources. However, if it is an image that has been persisted to an asset you can get that information from the band metadata. Bands within an image can different sizes and coordinate reference systems, so there is not necessarily one answer to what you are asking. To see the crs, resolution, and image sizes - print out the metadata of the image.

```js
ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR")
  .first()
  .evaluate(
    function(img) {
      print(img.bands);
    }   
  );
```

Which yields an array of objects like this:

```js
{
   "id":"B1",
   "data_type":{
      "type":"PixelType",
      "precision":"int",
      "min":0,
      "max":65535
   },
   "dimensions":[
      1830,
      1830
   ],
   "crs":"EPSG:32635",
   "crs_transform":[
      60,
      0,
      499980,
      0,
      -60,
      3000000
   ]
}
```

The `dimensions` are the  x and y size in pixels, and the 0 and 4 index of the `crs_transform` are the x and y pixel resolutions, respectively.